# Monaca + AngularJS + Onsen UI での Javascript の管理方法について

Tags: monaca, angularjs

Monaca + AngularJS + Onsen UI で画面がたくさんあるアプリの作成を考えています。
サンプルやチュートリアルでは、app.js のみが存在しますが、画面毎のコントローラや共通のサービス等で javascriptファイルを分割したい思っています。
この場合、index.html でそれらのファイルを全て読み込んでおかなければならないのでしょうか？

`navigator.pushPage` 等で遷移した先で 必要なjavascriptを読み込むことは出来ないでしょうか？
個別に読み込んだとしても

```
angular.module('my-app').controller('Page1Controller', ['$log', Page1Controller])
```

とすると、moduleに追加されて管理される？ので、最初に全て読むのと変わらない気もしますが・・・。

monacaでのアプリ作成する場合に javascript ファイルの分割方法と
それらの読み込み方法（最初に一気に読み込む or 画面毎に読み込む）について
app.js 以外のファイルを読み込んで開発している方がいましたら、教えてください。

以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問の投稿ありがとうございます。細かいですが、「Tips等を教えてください」と質問の範囲を広げる表現は、[質問の幅が広すぎる](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/30)、ととらえられる可能性があります。「分割方法を教えてください」のような具体的な質問で締めるとよいかなと思います。(質問は後から[edit]できます)

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。
stackovreflow 初心者のため勉強になります。質問内容もコードが見やすくなるように編集くださり、ありがとうございました。
以後気をつけますね。。

Comment: 私個人のコメントになってしまうのですが、grantやgulpなどでビルドするときに便利なので、全てindex.htmlでロードしてます。そのほうがメンテンナンスもしやすいと思います。

Comment: 自分もindex.htmlで全てのJavaScriptを読み込んでいます。その上でなのですが、逆に全て最初に読み込むことで起こる問題ってなんでしょうか？それぞれの派生でJavaScriptを読み込みたい気持ちは別の言語でインポート文を書く事もあるので分からなくもないのですがメリットが思い浮かびません。どの道AngularJSで読み込まれキャッシュされてしまいますし……。どうしてもやるのであれば動的にスクリプトタグを挿入するか、ソースコードをデータとして持ちevalするかですが……そこまでしてやるものなのでしょうか？意図が不明なので大仰な事を書いてしまいましたが、行いたい事だけではなく行う目的もあると回答もつけやすいのではないでしょうか？